# How to close specific socket between JAVA client and Active-MQ queue

Tags: java, sockets, activemq-classic

I have to test a specific scenario by closing the Active-MQ consumer socket without killing the java client process and Active-MQ server.
what is the best way to close specific socket between JAVA client and Active-MQ queue?

Answer (score 0):

maybe by calling `org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQMessageConsumer.close()` or `org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.close()` to close all sessions of consumers/producers

**UPDATE**
you can use VisualVM and call stop method, [image: see here]

Please consider that if your client is using failover he will reconnect automatically

or by code like below

to close 1 consumer by ID or RemoteAddress

> ```
> import java.util.HashMap;
> import java.util.Map;
> import java.util.Set;
>
> import javax.management.MBeanServerConnection;
> import javax.management.MBeanServerInvocationHandler;
> import javax.management.ObjectName;
> import javax.management.remote.JMXConnector;
> import javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory;
> import javax.management.remote.JMXServiceURL;
>
> import org.apache.activemq.broker.jmx.ConnectionViewMBean;
>
> public class JMXCloseConsumer {
>
>   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
>       JMXServiceURL url = new JMXServiceURL("service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:1099/jmxrmi");
>       Map<String, String[]> env = new HashMap<>();
>       String[] creds = { "admin", "admin" };
>       env.put(JMXConnector.CREDENTIALS, creds);
>       JMXConnector jmxc = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(url, env);
>       MBeanServerConnection conn = jmxc.getMBeanServerConnection();
>       ObjectName conName = new ObjectName(
>               "org.apache.activemq:type=Broker,brokerName=localhost,connector=clientConnectors,connectorName=openwire,connectionViewType=clientId,connectionName=*");
>       Set connections = conn.queryNames(conName, null);
>       Object[] c = connections.toArray();
>       for (int s = 0; s < c.length; s++) {
>           ObjectName con = (ObjectName) c[s];
>           System.out.println(con.toString());
>           ConnectionViewMBean connectionView = MBeanServerInvocationHandler.newProxyInstance(conn, con,
>                   ConnectionViewMBean.class, true);
>           String address = connectionView.getRemoteAddress();
>           System.out.println(address);
>           connectionView.stop();
>       }
>   }
> }
> ```

to close all consumers by connector name

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.management.MBeanServerConnection;
import javax.management.MBeanServerInvocationHandler;
import javax.management.ObjectName;
import javax.management.remote.JMXConnector;
import javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory;
import javax.management.remote.JMXServiceURL;

import org.apache.activemq.broker.jmx.BrokerViewMBean;
import org.apache.activemq.broker.jmx.ConnectorViewMBean;

public class JMXCloseAllConsumers {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JMXServiceURL url = new JMXServiceURL("service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:1099/jmxrmi");
        Map<String, String[]> env = new HashMap<>();
        String[] creds = { "admin", "admin" };
        env.put(JMXConnector.CREDENTIALS, creds);
        JMXConnector jmxc = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(url, env);
        MBeanServerConnection conn = jmxc.getMBeanServerConnection();
        ObjectName activeMq = new ObjectName("org.apache.activemq:type=Broker,brokerName=localhost");
        BrokerViewMBean mbean = MBeanServerInvocationHandler.newProxyInstance(conn, activeMq, BrokerViewMBean.class,
                true);
        Map<String, String> props = mbean.getTransportConnectors();
        for (Iterator<?> iter = props.keySet().iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
            String name = (String) iter.next();
            String value1 = props.get(name);
            System.out.println(value1);
            ObjectName connector = new ObjectName(
                    "org.apache.activemq:type=Broker,brokerName=localhost,connector=clientConnectors,connectorName="
                            + name);

            ConnectorViewMBean connectorViewMBean = MBeanServerInvocationHandler.newProxyInstance(conn, connector,
                    ConnectorViewMBean.class, true);
            System.out.println(connectorViewMBean.connectionCount());
            if (connectorViewMBean.connectionCount() > 0) {
                connectorViewMBean.stop();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

or

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.management.MBeanServerConnection;
import javax.management.MBeanServerInvocationHandler;
import javax.management.ObjectName;
import javax.management.remote.JMXConnector;
import javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory;
import javax.management.remote.JMXServiceURL;

import org.apache.activemq.broker.jmx.BrokerViewMBean;
import org.apache.activemq.broker.jmx.ConnectionViewMBean;
import org.apache.activemq.broker.jmx.ConnectorViewMBean;

public class JMXCloseAllConsumers {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JMXServiceURL url = new JMXServiceURL("service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:1099/jmxrmi");
        Map<String, String[]> env = new HashMap<>();
        String[] creds = { "admin", "admin" };
        env.put(JMXConnector.CREDENTIALS, creds);
        JMXConnector jmxc = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(url, env);
        MBeanServerConnection conn = jmxc.getMBeanServerConnection();
        ObjectName activeMq = new ObjectName("org.apache.activemq:type=Broker,brokerName=localhost");
        BrokerViewMBean mbean = MBeanServerInvocationHandler.newProxyInstance(conn, activeMq, BrokerViewMBean.class,
                true);
        Map<String, String> props = mbean.getTransportConnectors();
        for (Iterator<?> iter = props.keySet().iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
            String name = (String) iter.next();
            System.out.println(name);
            ObjectName connector = new ObjectName(
                    "org.apache.activemq:type=Broker,brokerName=localhost,connector=clientConnectors,connectorName="
                            + name);
            ConnectorViewMBean connectorViewMBean = MBeanServerInvocationHandler.newProxyInstance(conn, connector,
                    ConnectorViewMBean.class, true);
            System.out.println(connectorViewMBean.connectionCount());
            if (connectorViewMBean.connectionCount() > 0) {
                ObjectName conName = new ObjectName(
                        "org.apache.activemq:type=Broker,brokerName=localhost,connector=clientConnectors,connectorName="
                                + name + ",connectionViewType=clientId,connectionName=*");
                Set connections = conn.queryNames(conName, null);
                Object[] c = connections.toArray();
                for (int s = 0; s < c.length; s++) {
                    ObjectName con = (ObjectName) c[s];
                    System.out.println(con.toString());
                    ConnectionViewMBean connectionView = MBeanServerInvocationHandler.newProxyInstance(conn, con,
                            ConnectionViewMBean.class, true);
                    String address = connectionView.getRemoteAddress();
                    System.out.println(address);
                    connectionView.stop();
                }
                connectorViewMBean.stop();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: for this I need to modify production platform code which is not allowed.We need to kill it from external unit java class or *nix command.

Comment: i have updated my answer, Please consider that if your client is using failover he will reconnect automatically